# SearchView OnQueryTextListener, OnActionExpandListener does nothing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am trying to implement SearchView in my project, but my onQueryTextSubmit,onQueryTextChange,onMenuItemActionExpand and onMenuItemActionCollapse are not working. My minsdkversion is 17.

my XML:

```html
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:visible="true"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

my JavaMain:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnQueryTextListener, OnActionExpandListener {
  ...

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, this);

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

   @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items

        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(newText + "hello");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "onMenuItemActionExpand");
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "onMenuItemActionCollapse");
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
```

Nothing is getting printed with the Log and nothing is shown with Toast

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Use a debugger and check whether the control reaches those mentioned methods

Comment: @Keshav1234 sorry for my ignorance but how i check that? i run the debugg mode and..?

Comment: Just use step over by adding a break point some where in between from the point you feel its necessary to check.

Comment: @Keshav1234 thx for the answers , i am doing the debbuging , and i think that the app never reaches those methods (i press the boton expand and nothing shows on the debbug log)

Comment: So check why is that happening since code doesn't reach those method nothing happens

Comment: @Keshav1234 "Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse" This is why I can not work well with the debbuging tool? im using a samsung s4

Comment: i am using a navigation drawer , still cant

Comment: I think you are using many devices hence that message. use a single device..